# How can I encode a network into a machine learning feature?

Tags: networks

I am developing a predictive machine learning model. The dataset is social media posts from Twitter relating to a particular topic.

One of the features I would like to incorporate into the model is the state of the social network $G$ defined by the users in the discussion over some time frame (e.g. 1 day).  The nodes of $G$ are the Twitter users, and two users are connected whenever one mentions or retweets the other.

This network might be interesting in its own right. But how can we encode information from this network into one or a few features to be used in a machine learning model?

So far I have tried calculating centralities of the nodes and taking an average over all nodes, however this is not proving very useful in the model.

Other ideas tried are transitivity/global clustering coefficient.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a network embedding (similar to the way word embeddings are generated from text data), such as [**node2vec**](https://snap.stanford.edu/node2vec/).

See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02590.pdf), and [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2019.00381/full) for some examples and details.